# Cookiecutter Django - Add field to signup form?

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

When I use django-allauth I can easily change the Signup form by just creating a new form and in `settings.py` add: `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = "core.forms.SignupForm"`

I was unable to successfully do this with Cookiecutter Django. Shouldn't this work in Cookiecutter Django since it uses django-allauth?

If not then how can I add or change fields for the signup form?